# Add a thread to handle only 1 socket per time

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

How can i add a Thread in that code to allow only 1 connection per Time... and when it finish .close(); open again to wait another? i tryed a lot of others things, like WHILE, if, and others variables, but failed to block the .accept(); while a connection is open ;/, and i dont know how to make it one threaded

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
public class Provider  {
    ServerSocket providerSocket;
    Socket connection = null;
    ObjectOutputStream out;
    String ocupado = "0";
    ObjectInputStream in;
    String caminhodoarquivo;
    Provider(){}
    void run()
    {
        try{
            providerSocket = new ServerSocket(2004, 1);
            System.out.println("---------------Aguardando por certidões----------------");          
            connection = providerSocket.accept();  
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(this.connection.getOutputStream());
            out.flush();
            sendMessage(ocupado);
            in = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

            System.out.println("Certidão de: " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
            String ocupado = "1";


                try{
                    caminhodoarquivo = (String)in.readObject();
                   System.out.println("Certidão: " + caminhodoarquivo);

                   JTextField paginainicial = new JTextField();
                   JTextField paginafinal = new JTextField();
                   Object[] message = {
                        "Número da Primeira Folha: ", paginainicial,
                        "Número Última Folha: ", paginafinal,
                    };

                int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, "Dados da Certidão", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                ocupado = "1";
                if (option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {

                    String primeirafolha = paginainicial.getText();
                    String ultimafolha = paginafinal.getText();
                    metodos metodosBD = new metodos();
                    metodosBD.atualizafolha(primeirafolha, ultimafolha, caminhodoarquivo);

                    System.out.println("Dados inseridos.");
                    Desktop.getDesktop().print(new File(caminhodoarquivo)); 
                    ocupado = "0";


                } else {
                    System.out.println("Certidão Cancelada.");

                }


                }
                catch(ClassNotFoundException classnot){
                    System.err.println("Data received in unknown format");
                    out.close();
                    in.close();
                    providerSocket.close();
                }



        }
        catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            //4: Closing connection
            try{
                in.close();
                out.close();
                providerSocket.close();
            }
            catch(IOException ioException){
                ioException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    void sendMessage(String msg)
    {
        try{
            out.writeObject(msg);
            out.flush();
        }
        catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Provider server = new Provider();
        while(true){
            server.run();
        }
    }

}
```

> Edit for the answer of user2511414

1) Server is running ok and recieve perfectly the first connection and finish it when i close the confirmdialog, and i can open another perfectly = OK

2) When i connect client1, maintain the confirmdialog open, and try connect the second client i recive this error in CLIENT2:

```
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at certidoesOrganizado.PrimeiroPDF$Requester.run(PrimeiroPDF.java:151)
        at certidoesOrganizado.PrimeiroPDF.enviacaminho(PrimeiroPDF.java:132)
        at certidoesOrganizado.PrimeiroPDF.geracertidao(PrimeiroPDF.java:466)
        at certidoesOrganizado.PrimeiroPDF.pegadados(PrimeiroPDF.java:302)
        at certidoesOrganizado.gui$6.actionPerformed(gui.java:204)
```

and in the server i recive this one:

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
        at java.net.Socket.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
        at Provider.run(Provider.java:21)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Provider.run(Provider.java:59)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

and the Client2 doesnt recive a "Server is busy message"

3) While the client1 ConfirmDialog is still open and after the fail of Client2 i try the CLIENT3, it connect succefully and i end with 2 Joption.ShowConfirmDialog opened... :(

and everything start again, im using this in CLIENT's to do the connection:

in a method to call the connection:

```
Requester client = new Requester();

client.run();
```

Class Requester:

```
}
class Requester{
    Socket requestSock

et;
        ObjectOutputStream out;
    ObjectInputStream in;
    String message;

    Requester(){}
    void run()



    {




        try{

                requestSocket = new Socket("localhost", 2004);



            System.out.println("Tentando Conexão");
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(requestSocket.getOutputStream());
            out.flush();            
            System.out.println("out.flush");
            in = new ObjectInputStream(requestSocket.getInputStream());

                try {
                    message = (String)in.readObject();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }







            do{
               message = "oi";
                sendMessage(arquivonomecompleto);
            }while(message.equals("bye"));

        }
        catch(UnknownHostException unknownHost){
            System.err.println("You are trying to connect to an unknown host!");
        }
        catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            //4: Closing connection
            try{
                in.close();
                out.close();
                requestSocket.close();
            }
            catch(IOException ioException){
                ioException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }

    void sendMessage(String msg)
    {
        try{
            out.writeObject(msg);
            out.flush();
            //System.out.println("client>" + msg);
        }
        catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }




}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see your code single thread, no sign of other thread, everything is run by main thread, second I a little confused about some parts, first you flush the output just after you get it, I mean you do not send anything but flush it!

```
out = new ObjectOutputStream(this.connection.getOutputStream());
out.flush();
```

so how do you see your application run parallel?!

and about the running the connection process in another thread(and single), it's not a very hard job, first implement the Runnable interface, and let the run method handles the connection processing.

```
public class Provider implements Runnable  {
  ...
  public void run(){//manages the connection but ONE at a time.
    while(true){
       server.run();
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] arg){
    Provider server = new Provider();
    new Thread(this).start();//start the connection processing with another thread.
  }
  ...
}
```

also you would have a simple [thread tutorial here](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html).
have a good parallel program dude :)

**UPDATE:** and for refusing the second ones (with some message) while the first one is in the process, so this is not a hard job too, but the first thing is making the process parallel, for doing this, I put(cut) the main method into another class, and let the Provider class handles the requests, also KEEP the ServerSocket(port) OEPN.

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
public class Provider implements Runnable {
   // ServerSocket providerSocket;
    Socket connection = null;
    ObjectOutputStream out;
    String ocupado = "0";
    ObjectInputStream in;
    String caminhodoarquivo;
    Provider(Socket s){this.connection=s;}
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try{
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(this.connection.getOutputStream());
            //out.flush();
            sendMessage(ocupado);
            in = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            System.out.println("Certidão de: " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
            String ocupado = "1";
                try{
                    caminhodoarquivo = (String)in.readObject();
                   System.out.println("Certidão: " + caminhodoarquivo);
                   JTextField paginainicial = new JTextField();
                   JTextField paginafinal = new JTextField();
                   Object[] message = {
                        "Número da Primeira Folha: ", paginainicial,
                        "Número Última Folha: ", paginafinal,
                    };
                int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, "Dados da Certidão", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                ocupado = "1";
                if (option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                    String primeirafolha = paginainicial.getText();
                    String ultimafolha = paginafinal.getText();
                    metodos metodosBD = new metodos();
                    metodosBD.atualizafolha(primeirafolha, ultimafolha, caminhodoarquivo);
                    System.out.println("Dados inseridos.");
                    Desktop.getDesktop().print(new File(caminhodoarquivo)); 
                    ocupado = "0";
                }else {System.out.println("Certidão Cancelada.");}
                }catch(ClassNotFoundException classnot){
                    System.err.println("Data received in unknown format");
                    out.close();
                    in.close();
                    connection.close();
                }
        }
        catch(IOException ioException){ioException.printStackTrace();}
        finally{
            Server.setFree();//Tells server the system is ready for new connection.
            //4: Closing connection
            try{
                in.close();
                out.close();
                connection.close();
            }
            catch(IOException ioException){
                ioException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    void sendMessage(String msg)
    {
        try{
            out.writeObject(msg);
            out.flush();
        }
        catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
//    public static void main(String args[])
//    {
//        Provider server = new Provider();
//        while(true){
//            server.run();
//        }
//    }

}
```

NOTE: this one response "Error -> Server is busy" as a String when server is busy, so client needs to check if server response single string "Error -> Server is busy" it means server didn't response anything else.

```
class Server implements Runnable{
  private final String serverBusyMessage="Error -> Server is busy";
  private ServerSocket ss;
  private static volatile boolean busy=false;
  public static void setFree(){busy=false;}
  public void run(){
    while(true){
       try{Socket s=ss.accept();
           if(busy){//if there is one connection processing.
              ObjectOutputStream out=new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
              out.writeObject(serverBusyMessage);
              out.flush();
              s.close();continue;
           }
           System.out.println("---------------Aguardando por certidões----------------");   
           new Thread(new Provider(s)).start();
           busy=true;
       }catch(Exception e){}
    }
  }
  private Server(){try{ss=new ServerSocket(2004);}catch(Exception ex){}}
  public static void main(String[] arg){
    Server server = new Server();
    new Thread(server).start();
  }
}
```

Comment: the out.flush was that previsoly i was using the SendMessage in the end, but i removed it, i forget to remove the out ;x sorry!!
thanks a lot the lesson :)

Comment: no, when i connectwith my client one program, and in the server it pop up the JOPTION.showConfirm, i dont close it, so i try another connection, it still possible to connect =/, it will return a error in the second client, when the Server Close the ConfirmDialog and finish everything with the First, i need something to refuse the connection of the Second Client while the First one dont finish =(

Comment: Okay, Okay, I got it, you know the applciation is working okay, because client would connect, but there is no response, so now you want to refuse the second one with some message right?! okay I'll update my answer.

Comment: yes, while the first connection is still open and it dont execute the .close at the  if (option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {, or in the ELSE, or error, refuse new connections

Comment: i will try and read it to understand, thanks, anything new i will post here again, thanks you SO MUCH :)

Comment: I happy (if)I could give some hand, and I update the answer again(1 min after the last command, so please refresh the page, because you may got the old one) :)

Comment: Hey, i tested it, it work for the first client2, but in the client3 (while client1 is still connected) it allow connection!

Comment: @user2582318 I updated, I just forgot one keyword, please recheck, hope this time works.

Comment: Working Perfectly, you are the master of masters ;*

Comment: @user2582318 I really happy I could give some hand, have a good socket application buddy :)